# Is there a JDBC command to disable indexes in a table

Tags: jdbc, indexing

I've written some Java code to use JDBC to copy the contents of a table from one DB to another (it requires that the table exist in both DBs, it does not check the target table for the existence of any of the data it's copying over).

It uses PreparedStatements, and copies in blocks of 10,000.  I would like to add the ability to disable all indexes / foreign key constraints, and then re-enable them when the table has been completely copied over.

Is there a way to do this using pure JDBC, i.e. not just firing over some vendor specific code?

Comment: Which database are you using? JDBC is just a database-agnostic API, and this falls in the realm of database-specific functionality that is not part of JDBC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If there's only DB specific ways to do this, the answer would be "no". :-(

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, there isn't.

Longer answer:
Given a java.sql.Connection theConnection:

```
DatabaseMetaData    metaData = theConnection.getMetaData ();
String              dbType = metaData.getDatabaseProductName ();
String              command;
```

for "MySQL":

```
command = "ALTER TABLE <tableName> [ENABLE | DISABLE] KEYS;"
```

for "Microsoft SQL Server":

```
command = "ALTER INDEX ALL ON <tableName> [REBUILD | DISABLE];"
```

(feel encouraged to add other DB commands below.)  Once you have command, execute it

```
Statement   stmt = theConnection.createStatement ();
stmt.execute (command);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in JDBC itself that provides such functionality. You will need to use database specific functionality to do this.